# Matching Strings Using Next Match as Delimiter

Tags: regex, powershell, text

When matching rough text file via regex I want to match strings between and including matches; before writing these to a file. Because of the random nature of the text I cannot delimit matches using full stops or newlines. However I can write the matched component of the string. But I want the whole string.

Example text file has jumbled entries

```
# this text file replicates a jumbled double listing
001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street006 JOHNS, Jason .... 3 Steep Street 002 BROWN,
James .... 101 Browns Road
005 INSTONE, June .... 14 Dover Road 003 BROWN, Jemmima ........ 101 Browns Road 004 BROWN, John ....... 
101 Browns Road 
005 CAMPBELL, Colin ..... 57 Camp Avenue
004 HANNAH, Harold ....7 Right Way
006 DONNAGAN, Dolores ...11 Main Road
001 EMERSON, John .... 13 South Street
002 FLANAGAN, Lesley .... 1 Lovers Lane
003 GREGG, Ian ..... 101 Short Street
```

Using

```
$regexRen = '\d\d\d\s[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
$result = select-string -AllMatches -Path $input_path -Pattern $regexRen -CaseSensitive | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

I can output the following in alphabetical order with this kind of output:

```
001 AAL
002 BRO
003 BRO
004 BRO
005 CAM
006 DON
001 EME
002 FLA
003 GRE
```

What I want is the whole string until the next match. And that, I would assume, this would also take care of the multiple BROWN name. That is return the correct alphabetical order of the Brown's personal names.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `(?s)(?<!\d)\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3}.*?\D(?=\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3}|$)`

Comment: Thanks for your input. It works as far as outputting complete strings. But the alphabetical order is lost. In fact I can't see any pattern to the output. :-/

Comment: Aplogies Wiktor. For my initial running of your regex I failed to specify the sort adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Wiktor's beautiful Regex you can do something like this

```
$regexRen = '(?s)(?<!\d)\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3}.*?\D(?=\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3}|$)'
Select-String -AllMatches -Path $input_path -Pattern $regexRen -CaseSensitive | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value -replace '[\n\r]' } | 
        Sort-Object { $_.substring(4, 5) }
```

Output

```
001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street
002 BROWN,James .... 101 Browns Road
003 BROWN, Jemmima ........ 101 Browns Road
004 BROWN, John .......101 Browns Road
005 CAMPBELL, Colin ..... 57 Camp Avenue
006 DONNAGAN, Dolores ...11 Main Road
001 EMERSON, John .... 13 South Street
002 FLANAGAN, Lesley .... 1 Lovers Lane
003 GREGG, Ian ..... 101 Short Street
004 HANNAH, Harold ....7 Right Way
005 INSTONE, June .... 14 Dover Road
006 JOHNS, Jason .... 3 Steep Street
```

Comment: That is an intriguing solution, but I don't think it can work: When I run it against the sample input, I get `002·BROWN,` as the 2nd output line, for instance. The reason is that your line-by-line approach effectively ignores lines where the pattern doesn't match, such as `James .... 101 Browns Road` and `103 Browns Road ` /cc @Dave.

Comment: I just realized that you probably removed the line breaks before the two sample-input lines that I quoted, assuming that they were posting artifacts only. If that is indeed the case, your solution works as advertised. /cc @Dave.

Comment: @mklement0, what I actually did was `Get-Content -Path $input_path -Raw | Select-String -AllMatches ...`.  I do see it does not work the same when I omit Get-Content and use Select-String directly, but I think @Dave figured it out on his own or only used a part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel. Good point: your solution is easy to adapt to the multi-line scenario, if necessary. It is definitely simpler and also faster than my solution (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- [Daniel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72094583/45375) is simpler and faster.
- The solution below may still be of interest for the following techniques:

  - Using `-split` to split a multi-line string in a way that includes what the separator pattern matches too, by way of a regex capture group (`(...)`)
  - Using `Group-Object` to process an array in pairs.

---

I suggest using the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator, combined with [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) and [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object):

```sh
$i = @{ Index = 0 }
(Get-Content -Raw $input_path) -csplit '(\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3})' -ne '' | 
  Group-Object { [math]::Floor($i.Index++ / 2) } |
    ForEach-Object { (-join ($_.Group -replace '\r?\n', ' ')).TrimEnd() } |
      Sort-Object { (-split $_)[1] }
```

Output with your sample input (with each output string enclosed in `«...»` to illustrate the individual resulting strings):

```
«001·AALTON,·Alan·.....25·Every·Street»
«002·BROWN,·James·....·101·Browns·Road»
«003·BROWN,·Jemmima·........·101·Browns·Road·»
«004·BROWN,·John·.......··101·Browns·Road··»
«005·CAMPBELL,·Colin·.....·57·Camp·Avenue·»
«006·DONNAGAN,·Dolores·...11·Main·Road·»
«001·EMERSON,·John·....·13·South·Street·»
«002·FLANAGAN,·Lesley·....·1·Lovers·Lane·»
«003·GREGG,·Ian·.....·101·Short·Street·»
«004·HANNAH,·Harold·....7·Right·Way·»
«005·INSTONE,·June·....·14·Dover·Road·»
«006·JOHNS,·Jason·....·3·Steep·Street·»
```

Note: If the input lines have *leading whitespace*, more work is needed.

```sh
$i = @{ Index = 0 }
(Get-Content $input_path).TrimStart() -join "`n" -csplit '(\d{3}\s[A-Z]{3})' -ne '' | 
  Group-Object { [math]::Floor($i.Index++ / 2) } |
    ForEach-Object { (-join ($_.Group -replace '\r?\n', ' ')).TrimEnd() } |
      Sort-Object { (-split $_)[1] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have only had time for a quick try out. I haven't analyzed your code in details yet. But I'm getting this kind of output: `TON, Alan .....25 Every Street 006 JOH`

Comment: @Dave, that is curious; I suspect you didn't use my command as-is. If I paste your sample input into a file and run the above command against it, I get the output as stated (sans `«` and `»`).

Comment: It is the same for me @mklement0.  When I run this code I get `TON, Alan .....25 Every Street006 JOH
PBELL, Colin ..... 57 Camp Avenue 004 HAN`

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel - it seems that there was yet another formatting-artifact pitfall: When I copied the sample lines, I copied them _without leading whitespace_, because that's how they are formatted in the question. If I copy them _with_ leading whitespace, from the question's _source_ text, the symptom surfaces. I've updated the answer to deal with the latter scenario, but I'm starting to think it's not worth it.

Comment: @Dave, this whole conversation highlights the importance of providing _representative_ sample data in questions, along with clearly describing any additional constraints that cannot easily be demonstrated with sample data alone.